# ¿Cómo puedo esconder mi barra de tareas en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vscode

¿Cómo puedo esconder mi barra de tarea en `Visual Studio Code`?

No encuentro el comando para poder cerrarla ya que se encuentra fija y no la puedo cerrar con `Alt`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente en `Ver` busca `Alternar barra de menús` y desaparecerá. Después de esto, para mostrarla y ocultarla basta con pulsar `Alt`

Comment: Me sirvio perfecto, pensé que no se iba a poder solucionar, muchas gracias!